# getting an error while fetching data from database (mysql). n="+".join(n) TypeError: can only join an iterable

Tags: python, mysql

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="Attendance")
my_cursor = conn.cursor()

```
                            my_cursor.execute("select Name from student where Student_id="+str(id))
                            n=my_cursor.fetchone()
                            n="+".join(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the value of `n` before joining if it is an iterable. Probably it’s `None`.